# TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray' when attempting to make plot using numpy

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

Using this piece of code i get the temperatures and date times then insert them into a matplotlib (plt) using numpy (np)

```
# get date times and the temperatures of a certain city, info pulled from request
raw_date_times = [item['dt_txt'] for item in s['list']]
temperature_kelvins = [item['main']['temp'] for item in s['list']]

# Apply calculation on each item to make celsius from kelvins
temperatures = [round(item - 273.15) for item in temperature_kelvins]

# Filter out today's date from list of dates into date_times
today = datetime.today().date()
date_times = []
for i in raw_date_times:
    date =  datetime.strptime(i, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').date()
    if date == today:
        date_times.append(i)

# Convert the array with integers of temperatures to strings to make both of same dimension
for i in range(0, len(temperatures)): 
    temperatures[i] = str(temperatures[i]) 

# get len of date_times and convert it into an array (i.e 6 becomes [0,1,2,3,4,5])
date_times_len = len(date_times)
    n = []
for i in range(0,date_times_len):
n.append(i)
            print (n)

# Plot out map using values
x = np.array(n)
y = np.array([temperatures])
my_xticks = [date_times]
plt.xticks(x, my_xticks)
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()


# date_times example = ['2020-03-17 12:00:00', '2020-03-17 15:00:00', '2020-03-17 18:00:00', '2020-03-17 21:00:00']
# temperatures example (before string)= [29, 31, 30, 25, 23, 22, 20, 23, 30, 33, 31, 27, 24, 23, 21, 23, 31]
```

However i keep getting this error:

```
    for val in OrderedDict.fromkeys(data):
TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'
```

I researched a bit and found that it means that something went wrong with the shape i think.
Is it because they are strings? If so then could you suggest a way to convert my datetimes into  integers?

Thank you!

Full traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "class-test.py", line 77, in <module>
    weatherData('gurgaon')
  File "class-test.py", line 55, in weatherData
    plt.plot(x, y)
  File "/Users/Ronnie/.local/share/virtualenvs/weather-d3bb5uZO/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 2761, in plot
    return gca().plot(
  File "/Users/Ronnie/.local/share/virtualenvs/weather-d3bb5uZO/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py", line 1646, in plot
    lines = [*self._get_lines(*args, data=data, **kwargs)]
  File "/Users/Ronnie/.local/share/virtualenvs/weather-d3bb5uZO/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py", line 216, in __call__
    yield from self._plot_args(this, kwargs)
  File "/Users/Ronnie/.local/share/virtualenvs/weather-d3bb5uZO/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py", line 339, in _plot_args
    self.axes.yaxis.update_units(y)
  File "/Users/Ronnie/.local/share/virtualenvs/weather-d3bb5uZO/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/axis.py", line 1516, in update_units
    default = self.converter.default_units(data, self)
  File "/Users/Ronnie/.local/share/virtualenvs/weather-d3bb5uZO/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/category.py", line 107, in default_units
    axis.set_units(UnitData(data))
  File "/Users/Ronnie/.local/share/virtualenvs/weather-d3bb5uZO/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/category.py", line 175, in __init__
    self.update(data)
  File "/Users/Ronnie/.local/share/virtualenvs/weather-d3bb5uZO/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/category.py", line 210, in update
    for val in OrderedDict.fromkeys(data):
TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'
(weather) bash-3.2$
```

Comment: can you add full traceback?

Comment: Tell us about `x` and `y` - shape and dtype (assuming they are `ndarray`).  What happens if you skip the `plt.xticks` line?  Or it you drop the brackets on `[date_times]` (why are you using the []?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this replicates a portion of your plot:

```
In [347]: date_times = ['2020-03-17 12:00:00', '2020-03-17 15:00:00', '2020-03-17 18:00:00', '2020-03-17 21:00:00'] 
     ...: temperatures = [29, 31, 30, 25, 23, 22, 20, 23, 30, 33, 31, 27, 24, 23, 21, 23, 31]                        
In [348]: len(date_times)                                                                                            
Out[348]: 4
In [349]: len(temperatures)                                                                                          
Out[349]: 17
In [350]: x = np.arange(len(date_times))                                                                             
In [351]: y = np.array(temperatures[:4])    
In [359]: plt.xticks(x, date_times);                                                                                 
In [360]: plt.plot(x,y);
```

My `arange` is a shorter and faster way on constructing `x` than your:

```
In [361]: n = [] 
     ...: for i in range(0,4): 
     ...:     n.append(i) 
     ...: np.array(n)
```

Note that I use `date_times`, not `[date_times]`; the later adds an extra layer of list.  I can't reproduce your error, but the unnecessary [] might be causing problems.  The `ticks` and `labels` parameters to `xticks` should have the same length.

The error looks like it occurs while creating the axes (xticks).  It's using an array (`x`?) as a dictionary key.  The error occurs deep in the `plt` code, so it is hard to trace it back to your inputs.  So it's easier to just examine the inputs (`x`,`y`,`date_times`), and make sure they look reasonable (expected data and matching lengths).

Same error here:

[TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray' when trying to plot a DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58966646/typeerror-unhashable-type-numpy-ndarray-when-trying-to-plot-a-dataframe)

though off hand I don't see what similar or different.

===

This plots ok:

```
In [364]: plt.plot(date_times,y);
```

but this produces the error:

```
In [365]: plt.plot([date_times],y);
```

(as with your `xticks`, this has the unnecessary brackets).

Comment: Thank you so much! btw for the for loop i used this:
`for i in range(0,date_times_len):`
is it okay?

Comment: You don't need the loop.  Use `np.arange(date_times_len)` to get an array of `[0,1,2...]`.  Or even `np.array(range(date_times_len))`.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this can help

```
#first import
from datetime import datetime

a = datetime.now()
#converting into int 
a = int(a.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))  #using strtime to convert datetime into int
```

Comment: so according to you i have to do this:

            `date_times = int(date_times.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
            print (date_times)`

??
where would 'a' get its value?

Comment: @beepbeep-boop you should use `date_times =datetime.now()` instead of `today = datetime.today().date()`.

Comment: yeah okay thanks, but wait, @Cb9867 , can we use strings to make graphs using matplot on the x axis and int on the y axis?

Comment: @beepbeep-boop or if you don't want the seconds and minutes in your program and want only the todays date then you should use what you are using `today = datetime.today().date()` but also need to chance this line as `%Y-%m-%d '`

Answer (score 0):

yes you can use string to make graph but your matplot version should be >2.1 or 2.2

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = ["ABCD", "EEEEE", "LLLL"]
y = [5,2,3]

plt.plot(x, y)

plt.show()
```